# Assert for any two values from Multimap that has value stored as List<String>

Tags: java, guava, assert

I am using `ListMultimap<String, List<String>>` guava dependency to store values kind of below

```
key: "fruit" values: <apple, orange, banana>
key: "fruit" values: <apple, strawberry, blueberry>
key: "fruit" values: <orange, blueberry, banana, apple>
```

I have to assert condition if it contain values = orange, blueberry.

i am able to do assert for entire values but unable to assert for any 2 values within map values.

```
List<String> expectedValue = new ArrayList<>();
expectedValue.add(orange);
expectedValue.add(blueberry);
expectedValue.add(banana);
expectedValue.add(apple);
assertThat(map).containsValues(expectedValue);
```

Any suggestions / ideas will help. i tried for predicates in Guava but not able to successfully.

Comment: You probably want a `ListMultimap<String, String>`, not a `ListMultimap<String, List<String>>`.

Comment: It has to be as ListMultimap<String, List<String>>, as i am storing entire table row value ... I have built assert to verify expected condition against entire row value now and it temp solved my need. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: A `ListMultimap<String, List<String>>` is analogous to a `Map<String, List<List<String>>>` instead of a `Map<String, List<String>>`.  Are you sure that's what you want?